# Getters and Setters for ArrayLists in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, getter-setter

How would I go about using getters and setters for an ArrayList in Java? Here is what I have. I think I am using the getter correctly, but I don't know how to use a setter for an ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<String> stringlist = new ArrayList<String>();
public ArrayList<String> getStringList() {
    return stringlist;
}

public ArrayList<String> setStringList() {
    // I don't know what to put here
    // I also don't know if my return value is correct
}
```

Comment: For setters, you want a parameter such as `setStringList(ArrayList<String> list)`, and in the function do `stringlist = list`

Comment: Would the return type of that method be an ArrayList<String> or void? Or something else?

Comment: You don't usually need to return for setters unless you are specifically told to. You can change the return type to void.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set the value, you would take an `ArrayList<String>` passed as a parameter, and you would simply set the `ArrayList` to the parameter.

Also, note the use of `void` rather than the `ArrayList<String>` shown in your question. Commonly, a setter method does not return anything.

```
public void setStringList(ArrayList<String> stringList)
{
    this.stringList = stringList;
}
```

Comment: Correct answer. You may also want to choose a more descriptive method name such as `setCompanyNames`, to fit the business logic meaning, rather than `setStringList`.

Comment: Is this copy the reference of the object? So if you modify the StringList from outer scope, it will modify it, no?

Answer (score 60):

`ArrayList` is a mutable container class, though, so you don't actually need a setter at all: simply have callers call `getStringList()` and then mutate the `ArrayList` themselves:

```
public final class DataHolder {
  private final ArrayList<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();

  public ArrayList<String> getStringList() {
    return stringList;
  }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  DataHolder data = new DataHolder();
  data.getStringList().add("foo");
}
```

On the other hand, the more common requirement is to *prevent* callers from being able to mutate internal data structures, so that your class can actually enforce its invariants on its data. `ArrayList` is always mutable, so if you need to return an `ArrayList` but you don't want your private state to be modified, you'll need to copy:

```
public ArrayList<String> getStringList() {
  return new ArrayList<String>(stringList);
}
```

Alternatively, if possible, it's better to widen the return type and then return some other implementation that your class can use to enforce its invariants. For example, if you don't want people to modify your `ArrayList` using a getter method, you could widen the type from `ArrayList<String>` to `List<String>` and use an unmodifiable implementation, for example:

```
public List<String> getStringList() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableList(stringList);
}
```

On the other hand, for the setter, it depends on how you want to handle the values. Normally a `setFoo` method *replaces* the contents of foo, which you can of course do:

```
public void setStringList(ArrayList<String> stringList) {
  this.stringList = stringList;
}
```

But most likely you want to also widen the type you will accept. For example, you could accept any `Collection` instead of just an `ArrayList`:

```
public void setStringList(Collection<String> strings) {
  this.stringList = new ArrayList<>(strings);
}
```

It may be more useful, however, to instead expose methods to mutate the underlying list in other ways. For example, perhaps you simply want to support adding new items to the list:

```
public void addString(String string) {
  this.stringList.add(string);
}

public void addStrings(Collection<String> strings) {
  this.stringList.addAll(strings);
}
```

If you do decide to expose a setter that replaces the value, you probably want to first check it for correctness. Since your class initializes the `ArrayList` in an instance initializer, most likely you don't expect it will ever be null. So you should throw an exception if it is:

```
public void setStringList(List<String> stringList) {
  if (stringList == null) {
    throw new NullPointerException("stringList must not be null");
  }
  this.stringList = stringList;
}
```

Java 7 added a new [`Objects.requireNonNull`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) method for exactly this purpose.

Comment: I think that this should be the accepted answer as it handles the important concepts of encapsulation, mutability/defensive copying and "programming to an interface" (using `List` / `Collection` vs `ArrayList` in your API).

Comment: Once I had created my setter and started working with the getter and setter, I realized this.

Comment: Fabulous answer. I liked in particular, how you explained "unmodifiable implementation" for `getter` and "exposing methods to mutate the underlying list" for `setters`.

Answer (score 4):

A typical setter would look like this:

```
public void setStringList(ArrayList<String> stringList) {
    this.stringList = stringList;
}
```

You can also consider returning `this` for purpose of [fluent coding](http://www.martinfowler.com/bliki/FluentInterface.html).

```
public TypeOfYourClass setStringList(ArrayList<String> stringList) {
    this.stringList = stringList;
    return this;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead setter function, you can use a constructor to assign array.
like:

```
public class CLL extends ArrayAdapter<LBean> {
  ArrayList<LBean> lbean;

  public CLL(Context context, ArrayList<LBean> lList) {
      super(context, R.layout.custom_layoutT, lList );
      this.lbean=llist;
  }
  //getter functions
}
```

Answer (score -3):

One of the simplest things we as programmers do is pass around data. The traditional way to do this is to define a JavaBean:

```
public class DataHolder {
private String data;

public DataHolder() {
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public String getData() {
    return this.data;
}
}
```

Instead, I prefer the C struct style of writing classes that merely hold data:

```
public class DataHolder {
public final String data;

public DataHolder(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
}
```