# How to store arraylist of objects in firebase database android

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a model calss which i used to create groups

```
public class GroupModel {
    String groupId, groupName;
    ArrayList<GroupMember> groupMembersList;

    public GroupModel(String groupId, String groupName, ArrayList<GroupMember> groupMembersList) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.groupMembersList = groupMembersList;
    }

    public String getGroupId() {
        return groupId;
    }

    public void setGroupId(String groupId) {
        this.groupId = groupId;
    }

    public String getGroupName() {
        return groupName;
    }

    public void setGroupName(String groupName) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
    }
}
```

when i store data using this model all the data stored except **groupMembersList** i don't know why.
I uses following method to store group data

```
mdDatabaseReference
                .child(getResources().getString(R.string.group_list_child_key))
                .setValue(groupModel).addOnCompleteListener(task -> {//multiple informations in with same user(instertion will add new information)
            {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Group Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Utils.hideProgress();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, task.getException().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Utils.hideProgress();
                }
            }
        });
```

where the **groupModel** is the object of above given **GroupModel** class.

Please suggest me as i am new to firebase.

Comment: Add `GroupMember` class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u dont have setter and getter for that arraylist
..refer this link - [Getters and Setters for ArrayLists in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33060592/getters-and-setters-for-arraylists-in-java/33060652)

Comment: does it matter to have setter and getter methods in model class as i uses constructor to initialize the groupModel